# Is it advisable to host the core logic of a react native app in the cloud?

Tags: ios, reactjs, react-native

I am planning to build an iOS app with react native and I am super excited to do so.

Unfortunately the deadline is quite short, so I am considering to use an approach [like this](https://github.com/ArnaudRinquin/sk-react-native), which hosts the app bundle in the cloud for the production build of the application.
This may be beneficial, as an api will be build for the app and I could simply change the code of the deployed app if the api behaves otherwise than previously assumed.

As this seems like a good idea on first thought and I am quite sure it is a good idea in terms of testing and continuous delivery I am not sure if this works out in production and if the application will be accapted by apple.

So my question is if such an application would be approved by apple and if this kind of structure provides any problems on the users devices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this tends to be good idea. Usually, application stores a lot of data (authentication, user data and so on) on it's own servers.